# find command from PID

Tags: linux, process

Is it possible to find the command line of a running process with its `pid`? the output of `/proc/${PID}/cmdline` seems that it removes the space character to it is hard to read the output.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993452/splitting-proc-cmdline-arguments-with-spaces

1. `cat /proc/${PID}/cmdline | tr '\000' ' '`
2. `cat /proc/${PID}/cmdline | xargs -0 echo`

Answer (score 25):

`ps` can show this:

`ps -o cmd fp <PID>`

`ps` can do a lot more. For infos, see `man ps`

Comment: For very long commands, this may truncate the command string.

Answer (score 3):

For example `1` and `2` are PIDs.

Shortest way to show command:

```
ps 1
```

Explicit way:

```
ps --pid 1 2
```

Show only command field:

```
ps -o cmd 1
ps -o cmd --pid 1 2
```

Documentation: `man ps`

Answer (score 2):

Put this script in your **.bashrc** file and source it

> $ source ~/.bashrc

You can invoke it with command *$pid* which takes PIDs as command line argument and gives process name, user(process owner) as ouput 
eg:

```
$ pid 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
PID=1  Command=systemd  User=root
PID=2  Command=kthreadd  User=root
PID=3  Command=ksoftirqd/0  User=root
PID=5  Command=kworker/0:0H  User=root
PID=7  Command=rcu_sched  User=root
PID=8  Command=rcu_bh  User=root
PID=9  Command=migration/0  User=root
PID=10  Command=watchdog/0  User=root
```

Script:

```
function pid(){
        if [[ $# > 0 ]]
        then
                for i in $@
                do
                        ps -e -o pid,comm,user | awk '{print "PID="$1, " Command="$2," User="$3}'| egrep --color "^PID=$i\W"
                done
        else
                echo "Syntax: pid <pid number> [<pid number>]"
        fi
}
```